# Kusto !has_any | where value does not contain any value in set

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a built-in way in Kusto to check that a value does not contain multiple items? I know that I can use has_any to check if an item contains any values in a set, but I can't seem to get it to work with an "!" operator.
Example:

```
let Employees = datatable(Id:int, Name:string, Position:string ) 
[
   1, "Bob", "General Manager",
   2, "Mary", "Coordinator",
   3, "John", "Sales Representitive"
];
Employees
| where Position !has_any("Manager", "Sales")
```

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

If I remove the not operator (!) it works, and returns info for Bob and John. But I want to reverse it from has any/contains any to does **not** contain any. I have also tried

```
| where Position has_any !("Manager", "Sales")
```

But it seems like any combination of has_any and "!" throws a syntax error and won't run. Is there a way to do this without listing out individual !contains statements? i.e. this is not what I am looking for:

```
| where Position !contains "Manager" and Position !contains "Sales"
```

This isn't a big deal for just two conditions but when you're dealing with a long list it would be much better to use has_any with a simple exclamation mark in front of it.

-- UPDATE --

I only recently found out that `has_any` actually does not pick up if a field contains any item in a set. To be technically correct, it only picks up if the field *has any whole word matches* from the set. To clarify, here is an example:

```
let TestTable = datatable(Id:int, FirstName:string, LastName:string ) 
[
   1, "John", "De La Cruz",
   2, "Susana", "Vanderbelt",
   3, "Stan", "Manlyman",
   4, "Henry", "Van De Camps",
   5, "Alissa", "New man"
];
TestTable
| where not(LastName has_any("de", "man"))
```

Take careful note of the results:

[image: Table results]

If you where to replace the last line with this

```
| where LastName !contains("de") and LastName !contains("man")
```

It would yield nothing in the results set. So if you're really going for "where field doesn't *contain* any value in the set" then as far as I know you have to write out each one individually, there is no such keyword where you can pass in a set for that functionality. If anyone knows of such a keyword please let me know in the comments or a new answer and I will update this question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you could use `not()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/notfunction

for example:

```
let Employees = datatable(Id:int, Name:string, Position:string ) 
[
   1, "Bob", "General Manager",
   2, "Mary", "Coordinator",
   3, "John", "Sales Representitive"
];
Employees
| where not(Position has_any("Manager", "Sales"))
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni! I had previously tried `| where Position not(has_any("Manager", "Sales"))` which did not work, but you got that syntax magic

Comment: NOT IN operation works great also!  ```Employees
| where not(Position in ("Coordinator"))```