How to use !has on an array in KQL
We have a KQL script we are using that we would like to do a !has query on an array in.
When we have tried this previously, it has failed as the !has query can only be used on a string, not an array (as opposed to has_any, which does work on an array.
I am sure there is something simple we aren't considering with this. Could someone please point us in the right direction?
We want to use a list/array of safe words in more than one place, is why we are wanting to use it.
A snippet of our KQL so far (that works, but is ugly)
`//Email to external domains from staff member
let externalDomains = pack_array(
"bol.com.br",
"terra.com.br",
"ig.com.br",
"itelefonica.com.br",
"r7.com",
"zipmail.com.br",
"globo.com",
"globomail.com",
"oi.com.br");
EmailEvents
| where RecipientEmailAddress has_any (externalDomains)
| where Subject !contains "undeliverable:"
| where Subject !contains "payslip"
| where Subject !contains "bill"
| where Subject !contains "ticket"
| where Subject !contains "voucher"
| where Subject !contains "tenancy"
| where Subject !contains "booking"
| where Subject !contains "insurance"
| where Subject !contains "travel"
| where Subject !contains "hotel"
| where Subject !contains "novated"
| where Subject !contains "tax"
| where Subject !contains "itinerary"
| where DeliveryAction != "Blocked"
| where SenderFromAddress !contains "payroll"
| where AttachmentCount > 0
| join EmailAttachmentInfo on RecipientEmailAddress
| where FileType != "png"
| where FileType != "jpeg"
| where FileType != "gif"
| where FileType != "ics;" //ignore calendar invitiations
| where FileName !contains "payslip"
| where FileName !contains "pay slip"
| where FileName !contains "bill"
| where FileName !contains "ticket"
| where FileName !contains "voucher"
| where FileName !contains "tenancy"
| where FileName !contains "booking"
| where FileName !contains "insurance"
| where FileName !contains "travel"
| where FileName !contains "hotel"
| where FileName !contains "tax"
| where FileName !contains "tfn"
| where FileName !contains "itinerary"
| where FileName !contains "recipe"
| where FileName !contains "rental"
| where FileName !contains "personal"
| project TimeEmail = Timestamp, Subject, SenderFromAddress, RecipientEmailAddress, AccountName = tostring(split(SenderFromAddress, "@")[0]), DeliveryAction, FileName , FileType, FileSize;`

We want to use a single list/array instead of the repeated !contains lines.
Love some pointers!
Thanks!

you can use not(has_any(...)). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151476/7861807

@YoniL. not(has_any()) is not the same as !contains(). has only find whole words like "abc def". It would find "abc". But if you have "abcdef" then it wouldn´t find "abc".

if you look closely, you'll see that the topic of the question is "How to use !has on an array in KQL". you're correct that 'has' and 'contains' are operators with different semantics. in many (though not all) cases, users can convert usage of 'contains' to 'has' and benefit from improved query performance, due to leveraging the term index. Users should choose the best option based on their use case and data, and should be aware of all options and performance implications in order to make an educated choice.

One solution could be to use mv-apply. As an example only for the first part of your Query:
let externalDomains = pack_array(
"bol.com.br",
"terra.com.br",
"ig.com.br",
"itelefonica.com.br",
"r7.com",
"zipmail.com.br",
"globo.com",
"globomail.com",
"oi.com.br");
let excludeSubjects = pack_array(
"undeliverable:", 
"payslip", 
"bill", 
"ticket", 
"voucher", 
"tenancy", 
"booking",
"insurance",
"travel",
"hotel",
"tax",
"tfn"
"itinerary",
"recipe",
"rental",
"personal");
EmailEvents
| where RecipientEmailAddress has_any (externalDomains)
| mv-apply word = excludeSubjects on (
    extend containsWord = Subject contains word
    | summarize containsAny = max(containsWord)
)
| where containsAny == false
| where DeliveryAction != "Blocked"
| where SenderFromAddress !contains "payroll"
| where AttachmentCount > 0


Thanks for the feedback all!
After reviewing and looking at other suggestions out there, we went with this
where not(Subject has_any (falsePositives))
where not(FileName has_any (falsePositives))
Works a treat with the existing logic we already had. Allows us to use the inverse of has_any quite nicely.
Thanks again for the input all!
